# C# cast object type

Tags: c#, casting

How can I cast object type to different type?

```
public T Get<T>(T t)
{
    if (t is TypeA)
    {
        TypeA a = (TypeA)t; //error
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What is `TypeA`?

Comment: can you try to ```TypeA a =  t as TypeA;```

Comment: Why even typecast? t is TypeA

Comment: Why even generics when the only possible type is `TypeA`? Using generics in a context where only a couple of known types is possible is a bad idea.

Comment: what's the error? https://dotnetfiddle.net/5WUFa8

Comment: I believe you have to cast to `object` first, but really any time you're checking types or casting in a generic method you usually need to rethink your design.

Comment: The error is "Cannot convert type T to TypeA" "Cast is redundant".

Comment: `TypeA a = t as TypeA;` working very fine :)

Comment: If `TypeA` is a value-type (that is when you declared it as a `struct` you need to use boxing which ise cast it to `object` before and *then* casting it to your actual type `TypeA`.

Comment: Your method will not do anything as it's never assigning a return value.

Comment: @Adwaenyth, actually I have return value, just forgot to write here sorry.

Comment: @HimBromBeere TypeA is a class, not struct.

Comment: Thank you all guys all answers are correct.

Comment: Why so many dislikes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this:

```
TypeA a = (TypeA)(object)t;
```

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to use `as`

```
public T Get<T>(T t)
{
    if(t is TypeA) {
        TypeA a = t as TypeA;
    }
}
```

The other would be to use `Convert`

```
public T Get<T>(T t)
{
    if(t is TypeA) {
        TypeA a = (TypeA) Convert.ChangeType(t, typeof(TypeA));
    }
}
```

Comment: No point in using `is` and `as` together.  Better to just do a `null` check on the result of the `as`.

Answer (score 1):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7tb2Fl

I couldn't get an error here. It will cast fine

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public class TypeA
    {
        public int Id;
    }

    public class TypeB : TypeA
    {
        public int name;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var t = new TypeB{Id = 1, name = 15};
        if (t is TypeA)
        {
            TypeA a = (TypeA)t;// no error
            Console.WriteLine(a.Id); // no error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//Just thought of it and not tested:

```
public T ConvertType<T>(Object obj)
{
    if (obj is T)
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: It's bad. It will refused any convertible types (such as double and int) incorrectly;
```double d = 9;
Console.WriteLine(d is int);
// => false ```